# JavaScript: все возможные данные пользователя.

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте.

Для статистики и просмотра ЦА хотел бы собирать JavaScript'ом все возможные данные о пользователях, например: ip, браузер, ОС, местоположение (хотя бы приблизительное) и тому прочее. Может существуют плагины для подобных целей? Или бросьте в меня хотя бы линком на эту тему.

Заранее спасибо!

**UPD:**  У меня мобильное приложение (HTML5+JS), поэтому серверными штуками и сервисами вроде Google Analytics пользоваться не могу...

Comment: Как определить браузер и ip и ОС ищите в гугле, с брауезром конечно проблематично но уже есть много решений. Местоположение можно получить по ip. А в общем лучше используйте http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Analytics

Comment: Юзер агент на стороне сервера $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], ip $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']. Место положение через ip http://www.geoiptool.com/

Comment: Определитесь какие именно данные вам нужны, "все возможные" как-то не сильно вяжется с форматом QA

Answer (score 1):

Всё, что здесь перечислено, собирается не JavaScript, а анализом логов веб-сервера. Причём несравнимо надёжней и достоверней. См. например, [тут](http://www.opennet.ru/prog/sml/50.shtml). На JavaScript, как правило, собираются дополнительные финтифлюшки, типа цветности, размера экрана etc.

Comment: Это я всё прекрасно понимаю, но у меня мобильное приложение HTML5+JS, поэтому штуки вроде GAnalytics и серверных фич у меня не прокатят. Забыл это добавить, сейчас обновлю.

Comment: http://modernizr.com/

Comment: @eicto По-моему это из другой песни. Modernizr вроде как отслеживает же фичи браузера, нет?

Comment: @Andrewsh, но у вас же в любом случае есть что-то на сервере, что будет обрабатывать данные, поступающие от гипотетического javascript? Тогда начните с банального: прозрачной картинки 1x1 с вашего сервера, которая генерится скриптом, который, в свою очередь, анализирует всё, что приходит от пользовательского приложения. Это уже и юзер-агент, и ip (то есть местоположение, ОС).

Comment: @klopp, я так понимаю у ТС'a 100% stand alone application, хотя, конечно, тоже вариант, но, справедливости ради, с помощью JS'a из под webview можно вытянуть куда больше инфы, проблема в том, что ТС сам не знает какая именно информация ему нужна :)

Comment: Статистику в любом случае нужно куда-то отправлять, где-то копить и  анализировать. Как это сделать без централизованного удалённого сервиса я слабо понимаю...

Comment: @Andrewsh - он как раз разработан чтобы браузеры могли вести себя предсказуемо-адекватно в случае неподдерживаемых фич.  В общем-то настоящего повода  для получения данных о юзере и нет.

Comment: Не совсем понятно, почему нельзя пользоваться Google Analytics. Не всегда есть возможность загрузить скрипт с сервера Google? В чем конкретно проблема? "Мобильное приложение" - что это значит?